# smoking and coronavirus

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, smoking

In the beginning of the coronavirus pandemic, there was some noise about smoking being a risk factor when contracting coronavirus disease. Then there was a deafening silence.

**Beginning of 2022, what do we know about the interaction between smoking and coronavirus?**

Specifically: does smoking make you more susceptible to:

- becoming infected with coronavirus?
- becoming severely ill when infected with coronavirus?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Since a smoker have a certain grade of damage in their lungs, and the Covid-19 affects that organ, is natural think that clearly a smoker who get in a Hospital by Covid-19 have more risk of present more seriously symptoms. (This is only my thoughts in any moment I pretend tell you that the above thought have scientific evidence).

Answer (score 2):

Smokers have generally more [ACE-2 enzymes in their lungs](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32269089/), which is the primary receptor for SARS-CoV-2. Some hypothesize that this means that having more ACE-2 receptors automatically means there is more risk of severe COVID infection, but the mechanism seems not so clear-cut (like nothing in the biochemical pandemonium we call 'human body').

Contrary to the above, it is hypothesized that the free-floating ACE-2 enzymes [on lung macrophages](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32522666/) may bind more virus particles, leading to *less* lung infection, and better response to infection (i.e. less risk of cytokine storm among smokers), further complicated since ACE-2 also stimulates [angiotensin 1–7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angiotensin_(1-7)), dilating blood vessels.

Still there is some evidence that ACE-inhibitors [may be therapeutic against COVID](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7265882/)
and [reduces pneumonia in general](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3394697/).

This seems to explain the much-publicized [French paper](https://www.qeios.com/read/FXGQSB.2) hypothesizing that smoking protects against COVID (through nictotine leading to more ACE expression), and conversely others [hypothesizing that smoking increases severe COVID risk](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32341101/) through the same mechanism!

I personally feel that if there is a correlation for smokers getting less severe COVID infection, that this could be explained because smokers tend to get more fresh air, and that a proper ceteris paribus will make smokers more likely to contract severe disease because of poorer general health. The nicotine/ACE story is interesting, and would like to see a more targeted experiment with nicotine injections, patches or chewing gum. Again, it [*could* help](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT04598594), or it could harm, the evidence is generally weak.

It is sometimes reported that there are less smokers admitted to the ICU than would be expected, but there may be confounding factors, and the statistics may not be trustworthy. At least, I don't have robust numbers readily available. (Sorry!)